# What is the max length of browser URL for Window.Open

Tags: java, javascript, url, gwt, base64

I have this GWT code that opens a new browser window to show a text file.

```
    Window.open("data:text/plain;base64," + Base64.byteArrayToBase64(textBytes), "_blank", "");
```

**My questions are:**

- How long is the maximum URL part that a browser can handle?
- And what is the maximum bytes that this code will be able to handle
  properly?

Comment: I think you will get answered your first question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been answered already at [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

You can only safely assume 255 bytes, though some browsers currently support higher numbers. If you need to send more data, consider doing so in the body of a POST request instead.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered:

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

The JS will operate until out of memory, but IE tops out at around 2K I believe.

Please don't do that btw...